# How to correctly position android layout without using Absolute Layout?

Tags: android, layout, positioning

im sorry this is a noob question but i suck at layouting. How would i make a layout that positions the flashlight_button so it would preserve the ratio between imageviews on top and bottom.

It looks okay on nexus s (800x480), thats what i want

...image ...

but obviously when i switch to galaxy nexus (1280 x 720), it moves the middle button a bit to the top, like this (so it doesnt preserve the ratio between top and bottom margins as designed on nexus s)

...image...

The layout is here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:padding="20dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/application_logo_description"
    android:src="@drawable/mylight" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settings_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/settings_button_description"
    android:src="@drawable/settings_button" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/flashlight_button_description"
    android:src="@drawable/flashlight_button_selector" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/powered_by_description"
    android:src="@drawable/powered_by" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ad_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ad_button_description"
    android:src="@drawable/freeml" />
```

so it just anchors the top and bottom imageviews to parent edges, and the middle button is just pushed down using layout_maginBottom. I am providing scaled images for different densities and obviously density pixels to express size, so as it seems it just not enough on a bigger screen.

Whats the correct way to do this? Different .xml files or .. ?

//Sorry i cant still post images, hope you can imagine it.

Comment: `layout_centerInParent` is the attribute you're looking for I believe.

Comment: could you post actual images instead of "...image...". It is not clear what the final result should be

Comment: Im sorry i am new here and need 10 reputation to post images...
@DeeV: i know how to center it, but i dont want the image to be centered, its a bit offset towards the top, its a design i made up in photoshop and im trying to implement this

Comment: @PavelDudka Thanks, I still need 1 point though :-D

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered placing your flashlight image according to the parent's center?
So for now you are pushing flashlight image down (according to the top image position). Would it be more accurate to make flashlight image center-aligned and give it some bottom margin (to push it a bit higher according to your design).

Comment: Thanks for your answer however this does not work, it stays centered even with bottom margin od 200dp

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flashlight_button_description"
        android:src="@drawable/flashlight_button_selector" />